# How to play audio in WebView (React Native)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here is my code...I dont have errors but still cant play audio. If I use URL everything is fine, but when I want to play audio from project directory, but nothing had happened.

```
source={{
            html:
            '<audio id="audio" loop> <source src="../../Assets/Audio/test.mp3" type="audio/mp3" /> </audio>',
          }}
```